# How to refresh or reload a App in Multitasking

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When my Iphone-App was already running and I try to go back to it then it cannot refresh or reload the news or tables automatically.
How could i set an automatic refresh on the quickstart of the App?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to the previous answer, you can do this in your app delegate's [`applicationWillBecomeForeground:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW21) method, which is called when your app is about to be returned to the foreground.

There's also the [`UIApplicationWillEnterForeground`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification) notification, which you can sign up for to allow any object (like a view controller, for example) to be notified when the app is about to return to the foreground. Either technique should get the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try go call code to do that like : `[self.tableView reloadData];` or `[self.myNetwork reloadNews];`